# a little complex Linq2SQl insert operation (Dynamic user control and page insertion)

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am really trying to do this but i am failing to find a way.

here is the scenario, i got a blog module i made for my clients, because it is a repeatative task, so i all i have to do is to just upload it to new client and he can start blogging, but some clients need extra custom fields, let us say he wants to add a phone number for each article author, or extra reference, but i don't want to implement it for each client because it is a custom requirement.

now to do that i thought of creating a dynamic user control with this extra filed and this code in the user control for example

```
Blog bl = new Blog();
bl.ExtraRefrence = " http://www.something.com";
```

load it into the blog management panel, but what i want to do is to have the ability to let user control use the data context in the main blog editing page, what i mean is that the main page will have the insert command, so how i let main page insert command see the dynamic user control value without creating 2 Blog objects one in page and one in user control.

sorry if i am not clear, but seriously this killing me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
Make the field configurable.

Pseudo-code:

```
if client.HasExtraReference() then
   <asp:label text="<%= client.ExtrareferenceLabel %>" />
   <asp:textbox id="txtExtraReference" />
end if
```

and the in code-behind

```
Blog bl = new Blog();
bl.Content = ...
....
if client.HasExtraReference() then
    bl.ExtraRefrence = txtExtraReference.text;
end if
```

The `HasExtraReference` method could look you some config.

**Option 2**
If have multiple extra and variable number of fields you could add a ExtraBlogItem table.

```
BlogExtraItem
-------------
BlogExtraItemID int
BlogID int
ItemName Varchar(50)
ItemValue Varchar(250)
```

Add the items you wish in the page, and then pass a uniform `List( Of BlogExtraItem )` parameter to the Blog.Insert Function

Comment: thanks man, but the thing is is that extra reference was an example, each client might have different requirement, what i want is some way to plug any dynamic extra new fields to the main blog insert function, or something like override for the insert function.

Comment: The problem is that the LINQ dataContext must be aware of the field in order to use and update them.

Comment: thanks alot man, but i think i have not been clear enough, it is no problem to implement the extra fileds in the user control, the thing is i want the Blog DB class to be in static class so i can use it from both user control and ASPX Page, i was able to make it in static class but the problem it doe not save the values neither of Page or user control, i think there is problem with Datacontext being a static class like this

namespace Modules.Core.Blog
{
   
    public  class DataAccess
    {
  public   Blog InsertItem ()
  {
    
     Blog b = new Blog ();
      return b;
  }
    }
}

Comment: If you add a field to the database, you need to re-create the datacontext to be aware of the changes. That must be your problem. But .. If you implement it as a list of attributes (or items, like the example in Option 2), you have the same DB structure and no problems saving.

Comment: thanks again mate for answering me, it is not that DB is not updated, it is that even main blog Fields are not getting updated when i use the Blog class as static class, i have noticed the same thing with datacontext, if you call it from a static class, then it wil lnot work, i dont know what is going wrong here